# Разбить строку по словам

Tags: c++

Необходимо разбить вводимую строку по словам.

> ***Пример***
>
> *Дано:*
>
> *qwe rty*
>
> *Получаем:*
>
> *qwe*
>
> *rty*

Написал прогу:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char *a;

    printf ("Enter string: ");
    scanf (a);

    a = strtok (a, " ");
    printf ("\nResult: \n");
    do
    {
        a = strtok ("\0", "\n");
        if (a) printf ("\n%s", a);
    }
    while (a);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> warning C4700: использована
> неинициализированная локальная
> переменная "a"

Ссылаясь на:

```
scanf (a);
```

**UPD.** Ещё вопрос. Как можно перевернуть строку задом-наперёд?

> ***Пример***
>
> *Дано:*
>
> *qwerty*
>
> *Получаем:*
>
> *ytrewq*

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::string line = "a line of text to iterate through";
    std::string word;

    std::istringstream iss(line, std::istringstream::in);
    std::vector<std::string> wordsVector;
    while( iss >> word )     
    {
        wordsVector.push_back(word);
    }
    std::reverse(begin(wordsVector), end(wordsVector));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что в таких работах не разрешают использовать стандартные библиотеки, такие как vector и algorithm, иначе теряется вся суть задачи - собрать велосипед самому и посмотреть как это работает.

Comment: Именно так

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать стандартную библиотеку регулярных выражений,
в ней есть итератор, который позволяет перебирать совпадения с регуляркой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s = "qwe, rt and asdf.";

  std::regex regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
  for (std::sregex_token_iterator it(begin(s), end(s), regex), last; it != last; ++it)
    std::cout << it->str() << '\n';
}
```